# What are the phonotactic rules of 促音 in lexical items?

Tags: words, phonology, phonetics, phonotactics

In comparison to 連濁, finding rules on 促音 seems much harder. If possible, I would like to figure out what the rules are, that is, in which positions 促音 *can* occur, and in which positions 促音 is *likely* to occur. (Limited to Kanji-only words, that is ignoring phenomena such as っ for emphasis or elision in speech, e.g. っす)

For most words, these rules seem to hold:

- 促音 not in word-initial position
- 促音 only in the last mora of a morpheme
- 促音 only in two-or-more mora morphemes
- 促音 only rarely before some suffix morphemes (者, 的, the like)
- 促音 only in /u/ or /i/ based mora

I have also observed:

- The rarer the word, the less likely it has 促音

It might be the case that:

- More 促音 in 音読み words

The general pattern is: C(u/i)CV -> っCV
Seemingly, most consonants can only reduce in front of the same consonant (so がっこう), but つ and ち seem to be able to reduce in front of the same consonant.
つ and く seem to be the most likely to reduce, but perhaps only because they are the most common.

Incidentally, these rules seem pretty similar to 連濁.

Are there other tendencies that have been observed, e.g. via corpus analysis? Are there other rules?

Comment: I don't know if there are "rules" per se, but 促音 often makes things more casual. For example: 蹴り飛ばす→蹴っ飛ばす. Also, when 促音 is added, it may also create emphasis: とても→とっても. When used for emphasis, it is almost always placed after the first mora. Here are some examples: ぴたり→ぴったり、ばかり→ばっかり、しかと→しかっと

Comment: Also I don't think the fourth bullet is true. っきり and っぱなし seem pretty common

Comment: @Shurim Yeah, of course, the whole っ suffixes (って too, of course) exist. I feel like those follow completely different rules though, probably because the 促音 there stem from a completely different source. It'd probably make sense to limit this analysis to Kanji-only words generally.